# Moving current site to Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I've been building a site (already hosted at a domain) for someone who wants the capability to edit it themselves but they do not know html and would rather be able to visually edit it. Has anyone moved their site to a CMS (preferably wordpress) while keeping the same look of the site and could give me some pointers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You would need to learn how to create templates for wordpress and then recreate your theme using their way of doing things. Its not very difficult for someone used to css/html/php but there is alot of functionality you need to take in so you wont be doing it overnight.

This is a good place to start: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

If you are simply looking for an easy to use WYSIWYG editor for Html you could try to implement [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) in your current site. I've used this myself and it is rather nice.